# Is there any way to copyright an Ethereum smart contract?

Tags: go-ethereum, smart-contract-wallets

Is there any way to copyright an Ethereum token smart contract or somehow prevent it from being copied?

Answer (score 0):

Absolutely, that's what the `// SPDX-License-Identifier: <type of licence>` tag at the beginning of a Smart contract is for.

For example, `// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT`.

Here are some common license types: https://opensource.org/licenses

Now,there's no way you can prevent others from copying and using your smart contract code, but if the type of license you used states that nobody should copy it, then you could sue whoever copies it.

More license types: https://opensource.org/licenses/category

Search for the one that works for your needs and use it.

Maybe you could get in touch with a lawyer for some advice.

Comment: Is it possible to let anyone that holds the token enforce the copywrite instead of just the smart contract creator?